# What is a strategy for creating reactive iterators in Python?

Tags: python, reactive-programming

I've been reading up on a lot of the exciting developments in [functional reactive programming](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754/) over in the Javascript world. I'm also smitten by Python's [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). I'm aware that iterators can be used to build co-routines, and now I'm wondering, what would be a method to build a *reactive* iterator, let's call it a "stream", such that iterating on the stream would block until a new value was passed in to the stream?

Here's an example of what I would like to be able to do:

```
my_stream = Stream()

for x in my_stream: # <-- this "blocks" the co-routine if my_stream is empty
    do_something_to(x)

# ... meanwhile, elsewhere, in another co-routine or whatever...
my_stream.send('foo') # <-- this advances any on-going iterations on my_stream
```

Traditionally, when an iterator completes, it would `raise StopIteration` and the for loop would end. Instead, I want the for loop (that is, the next call to `stream.next()`) to "block" and cede control to another flow of execution, be it greenlet or coroutine or whatever.

I think what I'm trying to do is avoid the signal/callback pattern, since callbacks are so awkward in Python unless they can fit into a `lambda`. This is what I mean by a "reactive iterator"--the flow control is inverted, and the body of the for loop (or whatever is iterating over the stream) becomes reactive instead of proactive, essentially an inline block callback that fires whenever items enter the stream.

So, has this been done before? If not, what pattern/library/whatever would allow this to work? Gevent? Tornado's IOLoop? greenlets?

Comment: How can an iterator be empty?

Comment: Well, traditionally, when the iterator is done, it raises `StopIteration`. That's what I mean by empty. Instead of raising, though, I want to block and cede control to another flow of execution.

Comment: Reading your question, I feel a resonance with `yield from`. Cannot be more precise at the moment, and maybe its a tinnitus...

Comment: The `send('foo')` command - how is that supposed to change the inner state of `my_stream`? Is it somehow filled with something else in the meantime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a lot like wrapping threading and queueing with an iterator protocol.

```
import threading
import random
import Queue
import time

class Supplier(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.queue = q
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    #This is the 'coroutine', it puts stuff in the queue at random
    #intervals up to three seconds apart
    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            self.queue.put(i)
            time.sleep(random.random()*3)
        self.queue.put(StopIteration())

class Consumer(object):
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.queue = q

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        #The call to Queue.get below blocks indefinitely unless we specify a timeout,
        item = self.queue.get()
        self.queue.task_done()
        if isinstance(item, StopIteration):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return item

Q = Queue.Queue()
S = Supplier(Q)
C = Consumer(Q)

S.start()

for item in C:
    print item
```

*EDIT: To address @David Eyk's comment*

You could reimplement my example using greenlets, stackless, or any other lightweight concurrent programming library/system, and the fundamentals of the example would remain the same. A stream (in FRP terms) is a queue, with all the scheduling, locking and synchronisation that implies, regardless of how it's implemented. To be fair, the queue has has the additional ability to buffer stream insertions, which may be undesirable, in which case, setting the queue's max length to 1 would cause stream insertion (putting on the queue) to block. A coroutine is a concurrently executed code block, whether it's a thread, or just an separate execution stack. The only difference is when switching occurs, deterministically, or processor controlled. I would caution though, that the idea of deterministic switching and flow control between concurrent code blocks is *optimistic*. Streams are inherently asynchronous in FRP terms, mostly because they rely on *interrupt driven* IO as an input source, which means they are not as deterministic as you'd think. This is even sort of true for streams that read from file for example, because of the variability in IO speeds caused by seeking, BUS congestion etc. The idea of explicitly (i.e. deterministically) switching control flow to another coroutine is functionally the same as synchronising at a certain point in a thread. The execution stack gets switched and the program pointer moves. There are of course lightweight and heavyweight ways to do this, granted. As mentioned elsewhere, the Consumer class could trivially be rewritten as a generator, which is an object that implements it's own explicit stack and provides an explicit method for yielding control, i.e. a deterministic microthread or coroutine. In truth the threading in the example above is an ancillary concept. Using send would also remove the requirement for an explicit queue. Then, if supplier were an event processor handling interrupts and converting them into event objects and putting them into an event queue (i.e. stream), we could remove the threading from the example (at least explicitly) but it would become a lot more complex. The point is, lightweight or not, threading happens **somewhere** in FRP, whether you see it or not.

*EDIT 2: A more practical explanation of the queue is necessary*

Trying to recast the consumer as a generator using a queue, is indeed trivial

```
def Consumer():
    while True:
        item = self.queue.get()
        self.queue.task_done()
        if isinstance(item, StopIteration):
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            yield item
```

But removing the queue in favour of using `send` and yield expressions is not so trivial once iterators get involved, or more specifically looping over iterators. The `send` method works in conjunction with a yield expression inside the generator, e.g.

```
def Consumer(supplied_item = None):
    ignore = yield ignore #Postion A: ignores_initiating None
    while True:
        supplied_item = yield #Position B
        if supplied_item is not False:
            yield supplied_item #Position C
        else:
            raise StopIteration()
```

The problem is the that calling `next` on the generator, as is done by a for loop, is essentially the same as calling `send` with None as an argument. Since there is no synchronisation between the supplier and the consuming for loop, it is possible for the Consumer generator to receive the following input sequence

- None (Required to start it going; received at position A)
- 1 (from the Supplier; received at position B)
- None (from the for loop call on next; received at position C)
- None (from the for loop call on next because the supplier is still sleeping; received at position B)
- None (from the for loop call on next because the supplier is still sleeping; received at position C)

This means the generator yields to the for loop: [1, None, None, None, ...]. Depending on when the Supplier kicks in again, sending to position B or C, the for loop might never even see the 2, 3, etc. So, it turns out, if you want to use your coroutine as an iterator, you apparently have to use a queue (or some other method of synchronisation) to avoid this problem. If there a way to specify where you wanted to yield **to**, e.g. only yield here if called from the supplier, instead of the for loop, otherwise block.

Comment: That's the general idea, and that's definitely helpful to see how it would be done using threading. I was using 'coroutine' purposefully though--coroutines are generally deterministic microthreads, rather than true threads.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see. Thanks for taking the time to explain all that.

Answer (score 2):

You must be talking about [generators](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator). Code reading from a generator (=calling its `next()`) blocks until the generator `yield`s something. There were a few enhancements over time ([PEP 342 - 2.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342), [PEP 380 - 3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380#pep-acceptance)) to ease the use of generators as coroutines.

One way to build coroutines with generators was shown by Greg Ewing, PEP 380's champion, in https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-August/007927.html (apparently, the code is used for simulation modeling). Here, there's a "mediator" routine just above this one to which it returns control after each step:

```
def customer(i):
   print("Customer", i, "arriving at", now())
   yield from tables.acquire(1)
   print("Customer", i, "sits down at a table at", now())
   yield from waiters.acquire(1)
   print("Customer", i, "orders spam at", now())
   hold(random.normalvariate(20, 2))
   waiters.release(1)
   print("Customer", i, "gets served spam at", now())
   yield from hold(random.normalvariate(10, 5))
   print("Customer", i, "finished eating at", now())
   tables.release(1)
```

Comment: Yes, I suppose a generator *could* be a part of the solution (e.g. @sirlark's Consumer could be trivially rewritten to use a generator in `__iter__`). I guess what I'm trying to understand is, how would the flow of control be passed off inside the generator?

Comment: There are two ways to pass off control, a yield statement which returns to the caller, and sending to another generator using that generator's send method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that be using iter() to call a function repeatedly. Pair this with a queue will give you the blocking behavior:

```
q = Queue()
insert_some_message_periodically_forever(q, period=1)

def get():
    return q.get()

for msg in iter(get, None):
    print('message {0}'.format(msg))
```

Note that iter() accepts a sentinel (e.g. None), you can send that value to the queue to indicate end of stream too.